# raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error) using 'pip install <<package>>'

Tags: python, pip, cvxopt

Trying to install cvxopt package using pip generates the following error message - how can I avoid this? Any other package also fails with same message:

```
raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing '//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so': dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/693

Comment: Do you have `openssl` installed?

Comment: https://chriskief.com/2014/03/25/installing-cryptography-via-pip-with-macports-or-homebrew/